# navigating to prev element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am at the element with class fieldValidation(bolded below). And trying to navigate to the label field inside `.fTitleCell`.

Here's what I am doing.

```
$(".fieldValidation").each(function(){
            console.log($(this).prev("fTitleCell").text);
});
```

The pattern of fTitleCell and fInputCell goes on for multiple fields and for each fInputCell, I need to traverse to the prev closest fTitleCell and grab its label.

```
<div class="fRow">

 <div class="fTitleCell">
    <input id="mainForm:j_idt139" type="checkbox" name="mainForm:j_idt139" class="checkbox-Access">
    <label onmouseover="FA.fixLabelFor(this);">*IP Address*</label>
 </div>

<span class="fInputCell searchField-ip_int" style="width:25.0%;">
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ga="http://gfs.com/">
        <input type="text" name="mainForm:j_idt139" value="" class="fieldValidation" onblur="filter.setAdvCheckBox(this);" onkeyup="validation.checkType(this, 'ADDR');">
    </div>
 </span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go back to the parent. Then to the previous siblings element and after that look for the label.

[JsFiddle as a working exemple.](https://jsfiddle.net/x7L2nwrq/2/)

```
$(".fieldValidation").each(function(){
     console.log($(this).parents('.fInputCell').prev('.fTitleCell').find('label').text())
});
```

Comment: how would I get the label text to log? $(this).parents('.fInputCell').prev('.fTitleCell').find('label').value  ?

Comment: Answer updated, Its `text()` to find the inside text of a div.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".fieldValidation").each(function(){
           var $parentRow = $(this).closest('.fRow');
           var label =  $parentRow.find('.fTitleCell label');

});
```

Comment: why are you going up to find .fRow? And when you do $parentRow.find('.fTitleCell label'); it gets the first match right? which might not be desired sometimes because you have multiple combination of fTitleCell and label

Comment: As far as I understood  you have the structure like
`<div class="fRow">

 <div class="fTitleCell">
     ...
    <label>
...
</div>
<span class="fInputCell>
...
<input>
...
</span>
</div>`
`$(this).closest('.fRow');` will find the closest parent row to the current input and then  `$parentRow.find('.fTitleCell label');` will find the nested label inside of this row

Comment: and if you need to find the text, you just need to do `var text = label.text()` at the end

Comment: ok I think I missed mentioning that I would have multiple combos of fTitleCell and fInputCell inside fRow. In that case, if we traverse to fRow then it would be extra logic to go to nth label inside that element. My bad.

Comment: Maybe its better to change html structure in order to have the same parent div for your fTitleCell and fInputCell tags